# One to many relation ship in symfony 2.7

Tags: php, symfony

I have two entities as below

1) entity one

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CallRequestComments", mappedBy="CallRequest")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="call_request_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
protected $CallRequestComment;


/**
 * Add CallRequestComment
 *
 * @param \Veritas\AdminBundle\Entity\CallRequestComments $callRequestComment
 * @return CallRequest
 */
  public function addCallRequestComment(\Veritas\AdminBundle\Entity\CallRequestComments $callRequestComment)
    {
        $this->CallRequestComment[] = $callRequestComment;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove CallRequestComment
     *
     * @param \Veritas\AdminBundle\Entity\CallRequestComments $callRequestComment
     */
    public function removeCallRequestComment(\Veritas\AdminBundle\Entity\CallRequestComments $callRequestComment)
    {
        $this->CallRequestComment->removeElement($callRequestComment);
    }

    /**
     * Get CallRequestComment
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCallRequestComment()
    {
        return $this->CallRequestComment;
    }
```

2) entity two

```
 /**
  * @var text
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="comment", type="text")
  */
  protected $comment;
 /**
 * Set comment
 *
 * @param string $comment
 * @return CallRequestComments
 */
public function setComment($comment)
{
    $this->comment = $comment;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get comment
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getComment()
{
    return $this->comment;
}
```

and i want to get entity two's record on base of entity one
as below ,

```
$resultRow->getCallRequestComment()->getComment()
```

it's give me erroe like below:

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getComment" of class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection"
```

can any body help me toget this value without using left join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entities are related as `OneToMany`, so `getCallRequestComment` returns collection of `CallRequestComments` entities, not one. You should process them as array in loop:

```
foreach ($resultRow->getCallRequestComment() as $callRequestComment) {
    $comment = $callRequestComment->getComment();
    // do something with $comment
}
```